# Caml query for date range not working in ecma

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Not able to get item collection by my `CAML` in `date range`, while able to get in simple `CAML` query.

Please any body let me know what is the correct format of passing date string.

```
function check_Submission() { 
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employee Sift Details');
    var startDateFx ="2015-11-17T20:21:11Z";
    var endDatFx ="2015-11-17T20:21:11Z"; 
    var StrQuery = '<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'>' +
                        '<Query>' +
                            '<Where>' +
                            '<Geq>' +
                                '<FieldRef Name='Sift_x0020_Date' />' +
                                '<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>'+endDatFx+'</Value>' +
                            '</Geq>' +
                            '</Where>' +
                        '</Query>' +
                '</View>';                              
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(StrQuery);
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);  
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded4), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed4));
}

function onQuerySucceeded4(sender, args) { 
    alert('Request sucwess');
}

function onQueryFailed4(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CAML query is exactly doing what you tell it to do..

Check your single quotes.. the string you build is messed up

```
var StrQuery = '<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'>'
```

Correct, you escaped the quotes

```
'<FieldRef Name='Sift_x0020_Date' />' +
```

Incorrect, either escape the single quotes or use a double-quote

Comment: hi Danny  thanks for reply , I think single quote  is correct because  same type query  working  for other type column but not working in date type column the problem is only for date type.

Comment: It is a free world, everyone is allowed to learn JavaScript in thier own time..

Comment: Hi Danny Thanks ,  my problem been solved achualy problem was <FieldRef Name=\'Sift_x0020_Date\' /> here you catch correct palace

Comment: Yes, you escaped the single quotes so they are included **in** the string..  Please mark the answer so it does not popup anymore in that list of 19000 unanswered questions. tnx